# Remove weekends from Burndown in Board View (TFS 2012 - Scrum 2.0)

Tags: tfs, scrum

I would like to modify the Burndown chart in TFS 2012's Scrum 2.0 Template so that weekends no longer show. I've already looked at [this article](http://2e2ba.blogspot.com/2011/08/tfs-scrum-templates-and-burndown-report.html), but unfortunately the solution listed there doesn't apply to the Burndown Chart when running from Board View.

[image: example]

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can modify it in Board View?

Comment: You can modify only report to exlude non-working days. TFS2012 update1 didn't fix this for Board view. Looking forward to Microsoft and still waiting...

Comment: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2792800-burndown-chart-should-exclude-non-work-days  It is planned to change this in some future update.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me? This is very non-extensible for being a...template. How embarrassing Microsoft!

Comment: This is fixed in update 3 and future versions.

Comment: I don't think it has Andrew, unless I'm missing something.  I've just installed Update 3 and can't see any change with the Burndown Board View.

Comment: Sadly it didn't make it into the TFS 2013 RTM :(

Comment: Apparently solved as from today!
http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2014-jan-22-vso

Answer (score 8):

[UPDATE](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2792800-burndown-chart-should-exclude-non-work-days): The burndown excludes the weekends on Visual Studio Online. Later this year, this feature ships with TFS 2013 Update 2 for on-prem customers.

See the announcement at http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2014-jan-22-vso.

If you want to configure the working days of your team, you can click on the gear button in the top right corner which will open the admin area in a new tab. Click on your team, and choose the “settings” tab.

<strike>The TFS team on uservoice explained recently that they started working on this feature request [Burndown chart should exclude non-work days](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2792800-burndown-chart-should-exclude-non-work-days).</strike>